# How to use webview as responsive in iOS

Tags: ios, uiwebview

can anyone tell me how to use `UIWebView` as responsive in ios.

as am using `UIWebView` object of `xcode` for show my websites pages. my website is responsive for all device.

but they cant open in responsive.

Comment: If `UIWebView` can do so then What CSS will do here ;)

Comment: i don't know about CSS am talking about i phone here not about CSS. any ways i have used story board with webview object its shows me responsive views without any CSS changes. please check and suggest.    @TheTiger

Comment: No You can't make any website responsive with `webview` if the site is not responsive itself. May be your question is not clear enough for me but as I can read here. The Answer is NO.

Comment: ok @TheTiger i will check it again but my all views are responsive its work in storyboard but not in .xib view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my experience.

if we use .xib view file than its not show responsive view on device.

so, for solve this problem i have used storyboard for view , and use Webview XCode object in it, its by default responsive for all sites. its seems good to me. please you also try and vote up the question.

Answer (score 2):

A UIWebView can't make a website responsive on it's own. It depends on the css of the webpage that you are opening.